# ImportError: No module named app_manage when running Django with django-cms installed

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x, django-cms

I had a local working django project based on django–cms. its not working anymore when i activate virtualenv. Here full Error message:

```
Ajays-MacBook-Pro:django-cms-release-3.3.x ajayvelu$ python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 6, in <module>
    import app_manage
ImportError: No module named app_manage
```

Comment: Have you installed the Python package that provides the `app_manage` module? (probably [django-app-manage](https://github.com/ojii/django-app-manage))

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying actually i installed the djangocms  structure and when i tried to run it in local server i got the followed error since i am new to djangocms so i am not able to get it. However i followed through the link given by you but i didn't found any bash cmd to install it at my mac all i got was a git repository so i am confused whether i need to zip it in the specific local folder or should copy it anywhere and then run it

Comment: Given that django-app-manage is indeed the required package (which we can't determine unless you post the relevant portion of your `manage.py` file), you may download the git repository as a [zip file](https://github.com/ojii/django-app-manage/archive/master.zip), unzip it, change into the extracted directory, and run `python setup.py install`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the manage.py instance that was created when you installed DjangoCMS. For example, if you created the CMS in `/app` you must set the working directory to `/app` and run `python manage.py runserver` locally.

If you run the `manage.py` from the djangocms source directory you will get the error you reported.